# Including Android Apps Into Android Image

Tags: android, android-source

If you're building an Android image from the AOSP source how do you package custom apps into the image? My understanding is that to build the Android image you follow the steps here: https://source.android.com/source/building.html and to build the Android SDK you follow essentially the same steps but build the sdk target (e.g. `make sdk`). You then use the SDK to build an application using gradle but how do you include the resulting apk as part of the Android image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways to do so.

1. By adding .apk file in vendor and let it be copied while compiling AOSP.
2. By adding Android.mk in your app. AOSP will automatically read that Android.mk and will compile that app.
   Example : https://github.com/LineageOS/android_packages_apps_Recorder/blob/cm-14.1/app/src/main/Android.mk
   https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher3/+/android-7.1.1_r28/Android.mk